# Magento 2: How can I put the default filter for a custom admin grid?

Tags: gridview, grid, magento2

I created a custom admin grid in M2 with ui_component. Each column has a filter, but I can't understand how I can add a filter on default?

[image: example]

To see this filter once I opened the grid's page.

Comment: You should show some code, simplified if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This :-**

[How to Create Admin Grid in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)